# Print not working properly on chrome but other browers are working fine

Tags: .net, google-chrome, webforms, crystal-reports

I have an application bases on old .net web form which use crystal report for reporting. It was just fine till yesterday, no changes were made in production server but suddenly, report print is not working properly.
In print report button click it only prints some footer sections only, but it is working fine in microsoft edge, brave and safari.

Webpage
[image]

Printing popup
[image]

What may be creating this problem and what could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with me. The problem come from Chrome auto update. I remove chrome, reinstall Chrome version 107-0-5304-107 and stop chrome auto update. Now I can't fine better solution than this.

Comment: Thank you Chan, I am currently using Brave browser instead of Chrome that is also working, If you found any other solution which can run in latest chrome version than please do reply me.